HTML page keep refreshing infinitely
Can someone help me?
I've already tried a lot of solutions here. But my page keeps refreshing infinitely when I open the HTML on the live server.
The HTML form code is:
<form class="newItem" onsubmit="return false">
    <input type="text" id="newInput" placeholder="Nome">
    <input type="text" id="newPreg" placeholder="Pregancies">
    <input type="text" id="newPlas" placeholder="Glucose">
    <input type="text" id="newPres" placeholder="Blood Pressure">
    <input type="text" id="newSkin" placeholder="Skin Thickness">
    <input type="text" id="newTest" placeholder="Insulin">
    <input type="text" id="newMass" placeholder="BMI">
    <input type="text" id="newPedi" placeholder="Diabetes Pedigree Function">
    <input type="text" id="newAge" placeholder="Age">
    <button type="button" onclick="newItem(event)" class="addBtn">Diagnosticar</button>
</form>

And the Script.js is:

const getList = async () => {
  let url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/pacientes';
  fetch(url, {
    method: 'get',
  })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      data.pacientes.forEach(item => insertList(item.name, 
                                                item.preg, 
                                                item.plas,
                                                item.pres,
                                                item.skin,
                                                item.test,
                                                item.mass,
                                                item.pedi,
                                                item.age,
                                                item.outcome
                                              ))
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error('Error:', error);
    });
}


getList()

const postItem = async (inputPatient, inputPreg, inputPlas,
                        inputPres, inputSkin, inputTest, 
                        inputMass, inputPedi, inputAge) => {
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('name', inputPatient);
  formData.append('preg', inputPreg);
  formData.append('plas', inputPlas);
  formData.append('pres', inputPres);
  formData.append('skin', inputSkin);
  formData.append('test', inputTest);
  formData.append('mass', inputMass);
  formData.append('pedi', inputPedi);
  formData.append('age', inputAge);

  let url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/paciente';
  fetch(url, {
    method: 'post',
    body: formData
  })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error('Error:', error);
    });
}

const insertDeleteButton = (parent) => {
  ...
}

const removeElement = () => {
  ...
}

const deleteItem = (item) => {
  ...
}

const newItem = async (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();

  let inputPatient = document.getElementById("newInput").value;
  let inputPreg = document.getElementById("newPreg").value;
  let inputPlas = document.getElementById("newPlas").value;
  let inputPres = document.getElementById("newPres").value;
  let inputSkin = document.getElementById("newSkin").value;
  let inputTest = document.getElementById("newTest").value;
  let inputMass = document.getElementById("newMass").value;
  let inputPedi = document.getElementById("newPedi").value;
  let inputAge = document.getElementById("newAge").value;

  const checkUrl = `http://127.0.0.1:5000/pacientes?nome=${inputPatient}`;
  fetch(checkUrl, {
    method: 'get'
  })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      if (data.pacientes && data.pacientes.some(item => item.name === inputPatient)) {
        alert("O paciente já está cadastrado.\nCadastre o paciente com um nome diferente ou atualize o existente.");
      } else if (inputPatient === '') {
        alert("O nome do paciente não pode ser vazio!");
      } else if (isNaN(inputPreg) || isNaN(inputPlas) || isNaN(inputPres) || isNaN(inputSkin) || isNaN(inputTest) || isNaN(inputMass) || isNaN(inputPedi) || isNaN(inputAge)) {
        alert("Esse(s) campo(s) precisam ser números!");
      } else {
        insertList(inputPatient, inputPreg, inputPlas, inputPres, inputSkin, inputTest, inputMass, inputPedi, inputAge);
        postItem(inputPatient, inputPreg, inputPlas, inputPres, inputSkin, inputTest, inputMass, inputPedi, inputAge);
        alert("Item adicionado!");
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error('Error:', error);
    });

    event.preventDefault();
    return false;

}

const insertList = (namePatient, preg, plas,pres, skin, test, mass, pedi, age, outcome) => {
  var item = [namePatient, preg, plas,pres, skin, test, mass, pedi, age, outcome];
  var table = document.getElementById('myTable');
  var row = table.insertRow();

  for (var i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
    var cell = row.insertCell(i);
    cell.textContent = item[i];
  }

  var deleteCell = row.insertCell(-1);
  insertDeleteButton(deleteCell);

  document.getElementById("newInput").value = "";
  document.getElementById("newPreg").value = "";
  document.getElementById("newPlas").value = "";
  document.getElementById("newPres").value = "";
  document.getElementById("newSkin").value = "";
  document.getElementById("newTest").value = "";
  document.getElementById("newMass").value = "";
  document.getElementById("newPedi").value = "";
  document.getElementById("newAge").value = "";

  removeElement();
}

The API is working perfectly on Swagger. The loop only occurs when I open the index.html. Sometimes the loop stops, but after submitting a form it returns the loop.

I don't see anything in the JavaScript that would cause the code to run repeatedly.

Why don't you inspect the Network tab in developer tools and see if you can spot there, or in other places in your JS code which line creates that stall?

Why is newItem declared async? You never use await.

There's also no reason to call event.preventDefault() twice.

The issue you're experiencing with the infinite refresh loop is likely related to how your form submission and event handling are set up.

Duplicate Event Prevention: You're calling event.preventDefault()
twice and also returning false in the newItem function, which might
cause unintended behavior. This isn't necessary and could lead to
issues with event handling.
Form Submission Handling: The form's onsubmit="return false" combined
with the button's onclick="newItem(event)" should theoretically
prevent the default form submission, but since there's a complex
event flow, redundant code can cause unpredictable results.


Corrections :
Instead of returning false and using preventDefault in multiple places,
ensure that you only use event.preventDefault() once where necessary.
Ensure that the form itself doesn’t cause a page reload by removing the
onsubmit="return false" and relying solely on the button click event to
handle the form:


const newItem = async (event) => {
  event.preventDefault(); // Prevent form submission once
  
  let inputPatient = document.getElementById("newInput").value;
  let inputPreg = document.getElementById("newPreg").value;
  let inputPlas = document.getElementById("newPlas").value;
  let inputPres = document.getElementById("newPres").value;
  let inputSkin = document.getElementById("newSkin").value;
  let inputTest = document.getElementById("newTest").value;
  let inputMass = document.getElementById("newMass").value;
  let inputPedi = document.getElementById("newPedi").value;
  let inputAge = document.getElementById("newAge").value;

  const checkUrl = `http://127.0.0.1:5000/pacientes?nome=${inputPatient}`;
  try {
    const response = await fetch(checkUrl, { method: 'get' });
    const data = await response.json();

    if (data.pacientes && data.pacientes.some(item => item.name === inputPatient)) {
      alert("O paciente já está cadastrado.\nCadastre o paciente com um nome diferente ou atualize o existente.");
    } else if (inputPatient === '') {
      alert("O nome do paciente não pode ser vazio!");
    } else if (isNaN(inputPreg) || isNaN(inputPlas) || isNaN(inputPres) || isNaN(inputSkin) || isNaN(inputTest) || isNaN(inputMass) || isNaN(inputPedi) || isNaN(inputAge)) {
      alert("Esse(s) campo(s) precisam ser números!");
    } else {
      insertList(inputPatient, inputPreg, inputPlas, inputPres, inputSkin, inputTest, inputMass, inputPedi, inputAge);
      await postItem(inputPatient, inputPreg, inputPlas, inputPres, inputSkin, inputTest, inputMass, inputPedi, inputAge);
      alert("Item adicionado!");
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error:', error);
  }
}
<form class="newItem">
    <input type="text" id="newInput" placeholder="Nome">
    <input type="text" id="newPreg" placeholder="Pregnancies">
    <input type="text" id="newPlas" placeholder="Glucose">
    <input type="text" id="newPres" placeholder="Blood Pressure">
    <input type="text" id="newSkin" placeholder="Skin Thickness">
    <input type="text" id="newTest" placeholder="Insulin">
    <input type="text" id="newMass" placeholder="BMI">
    <input type="text" id="newPedi" placeholder="Diabetes Pedigree Function">
    <input type="text" id="newAge" placeholder="Age">
    <button type="button" onclick="newItem(event)" class="addBtn">Diagnosticar</button>
</form>




Check if you have a refresh meta tag in your html head tag
